# iphone sdk - Itunes connect how to change device requirements?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

What is it im supposed to set in the plist so that it shows that it does not work on the ipad on itunes?

its somthing to do with this http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html  but I dont see anything that seems appropriate?

Im still kind of noobish so I'd appreciate a really simple answer or as simple as possible.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Project Settings -> Build tab, Deployment category, Targeted Device Family.

Comment: Hi, I dont have that option in my Deployment section?

Comment: http://idisk.me.com/alex.babaev/Public/Pictures/Skitch/Screen_shot_2010-04-08_at_4.31.58_PM-20100408-163231.jpg It's XCode 3.2.2 final. Maybe it's only for 3.2.2, can't check right now.